# MySQL query order items based on next and previous item

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a table of items created with the following SQL code.

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
    `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
    ,`Contents` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    ,`Set` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`Nxt` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,`Prev` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ,KEY `Nxt`(`Prev`)
    ,KEY `Prev`(`Nxt`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Nxt`) REFERENCES `items`(`id`)
    ,CONSTRAINT `items_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Prev`) REFERENCES `items`(`id`)
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

As you can see each item reference it's previous and the next items it's related too and I have the following data in there.

```
Id      Contents    Set     Prev        Nxt
1       dakhd       1       NULL        4
2       234         2       7           6
3       fwer4w5     1       4           8
4       f34w5       1       1           3
5       234d233     2       NULL        7
6       1234        2       2           NULL
7       324         2       5           2
8       qw4         1       3           NULL
```

How can I write a query so that I have them ordered by Set, then take the item with NULL in the Prev column then take each of the next items example:

```
Id      Contents    Set     Prev        Nxt
1       dakhd       1       NULL        4
4       f34w5       1       1           3
3       fwer4w5     1       4           8
8       qw4         1       3           NULL
5       234d233     2       NULL        7
7       324         2       5           2
2       234         2       7           6
6       1234        2       2           NULL
```

I have the following query which will sort them by. the Set column however I'm not sure where to start with the ordering of the items

```
select * from `items` order by `Set`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with `case when`, assuming that `id` is always greater 0 the following should work:

```sql
select * 
from `items` 
order by `Set`
,case when `Prev` is null then -1 when `Nxt` is null then 1000000 else `Nxt` end
;
```

Comment: That almost works, however it has put the last item at the front

Comment: Changed the case when with another condition.

Comment: That's fantastic thank you, not used a case when in an order before, I'll have to remember that one for the future

Answer (score 0):

I think you do need a recursive query for this:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select i.*, 1 lvl from items where prev is null
    union all
    select i.*, c.lvl + 1
    from cte c
    inner join items i on i.prev = c.id
)
select * from cte order by set, lvl
```

The `with` clause selects the "first" item in each `set` (designated by a `null` value in `prev`), and then iterates through the dependency tree, while keeping up to date a counter that represents the depth of each node. You can then use that information to order the resultset.

Note that recursive queries are available in MySQL 8.0 only.